# scipy.interpolate.BSpline: Are there rules of thumb for the length of the enlarges x vector?

Tags: python, scipy, spline

I have code working to smooth some accelerometer x,y,z values in columns (toy data):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline, BSpline
idx = [1,2,3,4]
ts_length = 200

idx = np.array(idx,dtype=int)
accel = [[-0.7437,0.1118,-0.5367],
         [-0.5471,0.0062,-0.6338],
         [-0.7437,0.1216,-0.5255],
         [-0.4437,0.3216,-0.3255],
]
print(accel)
accel = np.array(accel,dtype=float)
accel_sm = np.zeros([ts_length,3])
idxnew = np.linspace(idx.min(), idx.max(), ts_length) 
for i in range (0,3):
         c = accel[:,i]
         spl = make_interp_spline(idx, c, k=3)
         c_smooth = spl(idxnew)
         accel_sm[:, i] = c_smooth
print(accel_sm)
```

I just picked ts_length = 200 out of a hat since I was only trying to get the example working. But I was wondering: Are there rules of thumb for how big it should be relative to len(idx) to do a good job of smoothing without making the smoothed array unnecessarily large?

Answer (score 0):

make_interp_spline does not do any smoothing, its result passes through the data.

For smoothing, use make_smoothing_spline or splrep.